CSS background-filter ignores transition duration (ReactJS)
I have a component in React that is a modal that only pops up sometimes. I can't post all the code because it's too much but I'll simplify and post what I can.
PROBLEM:
The modal is supposed to transition in with ease in that the blurring effect done on the background should be slow and transition (the transition is that it should go from no blur to blur(5px) in about 5 seconds). However, instead it just appears instantly, which is really jarring and almost headache inducing. I'm not sure why the transition duration values are seemingly being ignored here. How do I fix this?
I'm also open to other suggestions such as using react-fade-in or react-transition on the components instead if doing it through the CSS isn't an option.
NOTE: props.children is composed of several other components on bootstrap; it's basicaly the rest of my web app, with status being on top.
CODE:
export const StatusContainer: FunctionComponent<
    PropsWithChildren<StatusContainerProps>
> = (props) => {
    const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        checkSystemStatus();
    }, []);

    const checkStatus = async () => {
        try {
            const status: boolean = await getStatus();
            setShowModal(status)
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    };

    return (
         <div>
              {showModal && 
                <MyModal/>
              }
              {props.children}
          </div>
        );
    }
};

export const MyModal = () => {
    return (
        <div className="modal-container">
            <div className="status-container">
                <div className="status-body">
                    {'Hello World'}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

CSS:
.modal-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: backdrop-filter 5s linear;
    backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
    z-index: 10;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }

.status-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 150px;
  max-width: 950px;
  width: 75%;
  max-height: 75%;
}

.status-body {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: darkslategray;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
}


Transition from what to what? There have to be two states for a transition.

@Paulie_D it's supposed to just fade in basically; like the background, as part of the modal, becomes blurry but it should slowly transition INTO blurriness. So the transition is no blur to blur(5px).

So where is the "no blur" set? If you are just popping the modal in it's not going to transition at all. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331353/transitions-on-the-css-display-property

@Paulie_D I'm not sure what you mean, sorry. Is it not possible to make a component fade in by popping it in? If there's another way I can make this modal transition, I'd be happy to know.

The modal is appearing fully transitioned because that is how it's being told to render. In your CSS you have backdrop-filter: blur(5px); as a default style for the modal. The browser will therefore draw the modal with the backdrop filter applied from the start. There will be no animation because no before and after states have been defined.
You will need to first tell the modal to appear with a blur of 0. You then need to wait for a bit, until the component has been rendered, and then change the backdrop filter to blur(5px). Because there is now a defined change of style, the browser can transition from the before state of blur(0) to blur(5px);
How to do it
In your CSS, change your .modal-container class to have a backdrop filter of blur(0), and add a new class rule called blurred, which has the blur(5px).
.modal-container {
    transition: backdrop-filter 5s linear;
    backdrop-filter: blur(0);
    ...
    /* rest of styles */
}
.blurred {
    backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
}

We'll first draw the modal as normal, and then, once it's rendered, we'll add the blurred class to it. That will trigger the transition effect.
In your React for myModal
import classNames from 'classnames' // https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames

// ... other imports

export const MyModal = () => {
    const [isBlurred, setIsBlurred] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        // Uses setTimeout as a cheap trick to ensure the component is rendered.
        // May cause other problems
        setTimeout(() => setIsBlurred(true), 20);
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className={ classNames('modal-container', { blurred: isBlurred }) }>
            <div className="status-container">
                <div className="status-body">
                    {'Hello World'}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

This will only add the blurred class if the state variable isBlurred is true. We wait 20ms after the component is rendered (so we can be sure the browser has drawn it), and then set isBlurred to true.

omg that worked wonders; thank you! I was stuck on this for so long lol
